# How can I rank df rows by value?

Tags: python, dataframe, row, rank

df looks like below: 
`Age, Sex...` they are all index,with only one column named `Importance`

```
                        Importance
Onset Delta               0.121048
Site of Onset - Limb      0.000036
Site of Onset - Bulbar    0.000382
Age                       0.008650
Sex                       0.000978
Race - Caucasian          0.001274
Race - Other              0.001776
Sodium_Dmax               0.007689
```

I would like to re-shape the df, by ranking rows according to `Importance`,how could I do that?
I tried

```
groupby(['Importance'],as_index=False)
```

But not work
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [sort_values](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort_values) function:

```
test = df.sort_values('Importance')
```

assuming `df` is the dataframe

Comment: Although I believe `df.sort()` is deprecated. Correct solution in up-to-date pandas is `df.sort_values()`.

Answer (score 1):

If your data's structure is dataframe, you can use sort function:

```
df.sort(['Importance'],ascending=True) or 
df.sort(['Importance'],ascending=False)
```

The "True" or "False" depends on your option, it means your data are listed in descending order or ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

`df.groupby()` would be used if you wanted aggregations on the data, what you're looking for is `df.sort_values()`.

With `df.sort_values()`, you pass in the `by` string telling pandas which column to sort on.

For your code, I would expect `df.sort_values(by='Importance')`

You can assign the result of this to a new data frame, or pass in the `inplace=true` parameter to sort the df.

You can view the documentation for the `df.sort_values()` method [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort_values)